# SqlBulkLoad - loading xml to SQL

Tags: c#, xml

I posted earlier (and received valid answers, thanks) about a problem I had loading xml into sql. Ive got the code working to a point, but just not sure how to define what table to load the data to.

How can I find out the zero-based index of the table if I use the line below

```
sourcedata = ds.Tables[0];
```

Or, if I use

```
sourcedata = ds.Tables[Uploads];
```

how should this be formatted, as I get an error due to a type being used like a variable

thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "Uploads" is the *name* of the table, then:

```
sourcedata = ds.Tables["Uploads"];
```

Comment: in the WriteToServer line, am I supposed to put in the name of the dataset created from the xml Ive read in? (hope that makes sense...)

Comment: @Pedro not sure if that is a question...?

Comment: What I meant was, the xml reads in, I have the column mappings done ok, but at this last step WriteToServer([something]), I know [something] should be what it is Im writing, but through trial and error I cant quite get what should be in here.

Comment: @Pedro what happens when you use the table name? Or just Tables[0]

Comment: Just kinda times out and gives me a 'page cannot be displayed' error, but what you've said has put me on the right path now so thanks for that - think I just have a couple if things the wrong way round.

Answer (score 1):

You can get table based on name of table. your table name will be same as your xml tag name. for example if your xml is like below :

```
<root>
<customer>
<name>test</name>
<age>20</age>
<customer>
</root>
```

You need to access table using :

```
DataTable customerTable = dsData.Tables["Customer"]
```